# MongoDB get specific key from document based on given value

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting a Document as:

```
async findOne(id: string) {
    return await this.gameModel.findById(id);
}

async update(id: string, updateGameDto: UpdateGameDto) {
    const game = await this.findOne(id)

    // This gives all keys as expected
    for( const key in game){
        console.log(key)
    }
    // ...
    const keys = Object.keys(game) // [ '$__', '$isNew', '_doc' ]
    return;

}
```

Why does `Object.keys(game)` only return those 3 keys? If it only returns those keys, obviously I can't get the key as so:

```
const specificKeyByValue = Object.keys(game).find(key => game[key] === "SomeValue")
```

I could create a function that simply returns the key with a `for loop` like;

```
const getKeyByValue = (obj, value) => 
{
    for( const key in obj)
    {
        if(obj[key] === value) return key;
    }
}
```

But I prefer to stay away from creating extra functions if I don't have to. Any idea why this `Object.Keys()` variant doesn't work?

Comment: There is difference in behaviour of `Object.keys` and `for-in`. `for-in` Iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties.   Check these examples - https://gist.github.com/pajaydev/e8dfcbab883ce6742488c8b02e8f96ff

Comment: Ah yes... This makes perfect sense to be honest. Well a function is going to be it then. Care to make this an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few differences in behaviour of `Object.keys` and `for-in`.

`for-in` iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties.

As per the MDN docs this is what `for-in` does:

> The loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object
> itself and those the object inherits from its prototype chain
> (properties of nearer prototypes take precedence over those of
> prototypes further away from the object in its prototype chain).
>
> A for...in loop only iterates over enumerable, non-symbol properties.
> Objects created from built–in constructors like Array and Object have
> inherited non–enumerable properties from Array.prototype and
> Object.prototype, such as Array's indexOf() method or Object's
> toString() method, which will not be visited in the for...in loop.

And the difference ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#description))

> Object.keys() returns an array whose elements are strings
> corresponding to the enumerable string-keyed property names found
> directly upon object. This is the same as iterating with a for...in
> loop, except that a for...in loop enumerates properties in the
> prototype chain as well. The order of the array returned by
> Object.keys() is the same as that provided by a for...in loop.

Check few examples [here](https://gist.github.com/pajaydev/e8dfcbab883ce6742488c8b02e8f96ff)